# Networkstream or Serializing sending images?

Tags: c#, image, performance, stream

New to this, i have been using serializing for sending image data constantly.
Meaning i save an image in a memorystream, and send it with serializing.

But i don´t understand if i am supposed to use Serializing or Networkstream.
The only thing i am doing is sending images in a loop.

I have been trying to get a Networkstream to work, but it doesn´t go my way, so here is my code. It sens only 1 image for some reason, when i use serializing it goes constantly.

```
    private void Initialize()
    {
        NetSerializer.Serializer.Initialize(new Type[] { typeof(MemoryStream) });
        tcplisten = new System.Net.Sockets.TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 1700);
        tcplisten.Start();

    }
    private void Listen()
    {
        try
        {
            using (TcpClient tt1 = tcplisten.AcceptTcpClient())
            {
                tt1.NoDelay = true;
                while (checkBox1.Checked)
                {
                    panel1.BackgroundImage = Image.FromStream(tt1.GetStream());
                }
            }
        }
        catch
        {
        }

    }
```

And here is the send:

```
    private void Send()
    {
        try
        {                
            string process = Proccessname.Text;               
            using (TcpClient tcp = new TcpClient())
            {

                tcp.NoDelay = true;
                while (capcon == true)
                {

                    if (tcp.Connected)
                    {
                        PrintWindow(process, tcp.GetStream());

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        tcp.Connect(adress);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch
        {
        }  
    }
```

what  PrintWindow(process, tcp.GetStream()); does is simply, screenshot an a window (process = the name of the process), then where to save it (tcp.GetStream()) which makes it send and stream it (at least i think so).

It does work a bit, if i disconnect and connect etc, it will send an image, but it´s pretty random i think, not sure why i have to do that, i want it to keep sending as long as the loop is active.

(This works perfectly with Serialization and MemoryStream (save the bitmap in a memorystream and use it in Serialization) ).

So this is like 2 questions, depending on the answer of the first.

What is faster for my purpose, (Sending an image), Serialization or NetworkStream?
If NetworkStream is faster, how can i get it to work, what´s wrong with my code above.

Thanks

```
          if (tcp.Connected)
                {
                    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();

                    PrintWindow(process, ms);
                    panel1.BackgroundImage = Image.FromStream(ms);

                }
```

This works, so it is getting connected, and the data is getting saved (changed to MemoryStream instead of NetworkStream for this).

Comment: Your second snippet of code doesn't actually show the MemoryStream getting sent over the NetworkStream, does it?

Comment: Oh, saw that, ms = tcp.GetStream(), will fix that.

Comment: The second snippet of example code still doesn't make sense because you're making a new TcpClient and directly getting the stream from it without even being connected to anything.

Comment: Will give the whole code as i see that it doesn´t really make any sense.

Comment: Are you sure that's your whole code? Still doesn't make much sense to me.

Comment: Well it´s not the Entire code as the whole solution, but i have written the entire send part and receiving part. 

What is it that doesn´t make sense?

Comment: You define 2 TcpClient's called "tcp" in your second code snippet.

Comment: I changed and updated it now, as i have tried to modify and solve it. Now it should be a bit more readable, but it´s the same problem and the code just look a bit different.

Comment: Are you sure `PrintWindow` is getting called? (Put a breakpoint on it to find out.) You might also want to step into your code to find out if it's actually connecting and sending.

Comment: Well i do get an image, if i disconnect and stuff for some reason. And it works Perfectly with Serialization. And if i change it to memorystream, and try to show the image on the send part if tcp is connected, it works. So the printwindow works, and is saving to the stream. But the NetworkStream isn´t working. Or i am just failing at it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You say you get an image when you disconnect. That makes sense because you're reading the image directly from the stream. Since the stream is a `NetworkStream`, it has no idea when it has to end.

My suggestion is to add the size of the image buffer before sending the actual image buffer when receiving/sending it using a `BinaryReader`, like this:

```
BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(netStream);
while (true) {
  // read how big the image buffer is
  int ctBytes = reader.ReadInt32();

  // read the image buffer into a MemoryStream
  MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(reader.ReadBytes(ctBytes));

  // get the image from the MemoryStream
  Image img = Image.FromStream(ms);

  // ...do something with img
}
```

And when sending:

```
BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(netStream);
while (someCondition) {
  // get the image
  Image img = SomeImage();

  // save the image to a MemoryStream
  MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
  img.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);

  // get the image buffer
  byte[] buffer = new byte[ms.Length];
  ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
  ms.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

  // write the size of the image buffer
  writer.Write(buffer.Length);

  // write the actual buffer
  writer.Write(buffer);
}
```

Comment: I would like to not use a MemoryStream, and just save it directly to the NetworkStream which should be faster. I am trying to speed things up from Serialization. Where i had to use MemoryStream of Byte Array.

Comment: As my answer says, you can't do that because then the Image reader won't be able to know when the stream ends.

Comment: Hmm, weird. Or well not weird, it makes sense. But the thing is that i got a suggestion to to this, to write in a NetworkStream. But how does this differ from Serialization then?

Comment: Not sure what you mean with serialization here, but this is essentially your own binary serialization (I guess) by sending the buffer size followed by the image buffer itself.

Comment: I am looking to the fastest way to send images, and my lack of knowledge causes many problems, that´s why i wanted to give NetworkStream a look, compared to Serialization.

But your code doesn´t work for me sadly, not sure why.

Comment: Now i got it to work, i had ignored all the error messages, so i never saw what was wrong. But it seems i was trying to use it while the socket was closed:) Great,is this faster than using a serialization, like the inbuilt one for example?(maybe stupid question as i don´t really know what they do). Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I tweaked the code a bit, so just gonna write it here for other people.
Now sure if it´s better or worse though.
This is the sending part, i skip to convert to a byte[] and just use the MemoryStream.

```
                            using (MemoryStream ms = PrintWindow(process))
                        {
                            writer.Write(ms.Length);
                            writer.Write(ms.GetBuffer());
                        }
```

And here for the receiving part:

```
panel1.BackgroundImage = Image.FromStream(new MemoryStream(reader.ReadBytes((Int32)reader.ReadInt64())));
```

Put everything in one command.

Of course the BinaryWriter/Reader are there, but i didn´t put them here, as i am just showing how i changed the code.

I used Angelo Geels Code above*

EDIT: for some reason it only seems to work in .bmp, not sure why, doesn´t make sense to me.

EDIT 2:

This can be solved with:

writer.Write(ms.GetBuffer(),0,(int)ms.Length);

Think that´s the way.

Comment: `ms.GetBuffer()` doesn't always return a buffer the length of the `MemoryStream` itself, hence why I made it read it into a buffer in my code.