# How to tell when the Stream is at it's end?

Tags: c#, tcp, stream

How do I embed or tell the size of the TCP Stream to the receiver without using BinaryWriter/Reader?

There must be a fast way for it to know if it has reached the end, except of course, killing the connection.

```
tcp.GetStream().Write(ms.GetBuffer(), 0, (int)ms.Length);
```

I am sending like that, but receiving is the hard part.

EDIT:

This does not work for me:

```
                while (tt1.GetStream().DataAvailable)
                {
                    su = Image.FromStream(tt1.GetStream());
                }
```

Comment: Why do you need to get the length before you are able to read it?

Comment: Have you tried putting `tt1.GetStream()` into a temporary `NetworkStream` or whatever kind of stream it is before calling `.DataAvailable` or `Image.FromStream` on the stream? Also, I don't think `Image.FromStream` needs to be in a while loop - it should handle hitting the end of the stream itself.

Comment: Okay, will try that, meaning, copy it to a NetworkStream in a while loop, and read it after the while loop.

Comment: I mean just use `Image.FromStream(tt1.GetStream());` Does that not work outside of any loop without checking if DataAvailable?

Comment: Oh, not, it does not. Except, if i disconnect, then it works for 1 picture. (it don´t know the end, so it keeps reading even if there is no data, so if i disconnect, it forces to read it). Else it would be perfect, as i could read directly from the stream. Or wait it doesn´t work even if i disconnect if it´s outside of a loop.

Comment: You could somehow place a terminator in the middle of the stream that you could then interpret its location and split the buffer from the stream accordingly, shunt it into a new stream and read that from the Image class... But that seems rather tedious. What's stopping you from getting one image at a time?

Comment: Cant i just have something at the end that says "you are done?". What stops me from sending one image and then disconnecting is, it´s sending an infinite number. Think of it as a "movie".

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35607/discussion-between-rob-g-and-user2587718)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Networkstream or Serializing sending images?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18057024/networkstream-or-serializing-sending-images)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the .DataAvailable property in the receiver to determine if there is still data available in the stream to be read, but the Length property itself is not implemented.

Use

```
do {
    ...
    myNetworkStream.Read(buffer, 0, someSizeToCopyEachLoop)
}
while(myNetworkStream.DataAvailable);
```

If you really need the length of the stream you can copy its contents to a `MemoryStream` and read the `.Length` property of that:

```
MemoryStream s = new MemoryStream();
myNetworkStream.CopyTo(s);
int length = s.Length;
```

Comment: I tried that, but i have another while loop, and it seems to cause conflicts, as that while loop will be faster/slower than the DataAvailable, meaning it can get false/true when it´s not actually true.  Okay, doesn´t work at all for me, even if i try to only use that as a While argument;S

Comment: The thing i am sending is in a memory stream, so when i send it, i can easily send the correct amount of data :  tcp.GetStream().Write(ms.GetBuffer(), 0, (int)ms.Length); ,  But, the receiving part doesn´t know when it´s done.

Comment: I'm suggesting you copy the incoming TCP stream to a new MemoryStream that you can read the length of.

Comment: Oh, but would like to try prevent that, as it´s going to slow thing down. I am trying to be able to read directly from the networkstream (it´s an Image, so Image.FromStream), IT works if i disconnect, but that´s because i force it to read the stream, even if it´s not done.

Comment: I posted a comment as a reply to your original post. We could also move this to discussion or something if we're making too many comments here.

Answer (score 6):

No, there isn't a way (fast or slow) to tell when you've reached the end of a network stream. `DataAvailable` will tell you if data is currently available, but it can't tell you if more data might be coming down the stream.

There are two reliable ways that I know of to determine if you've reached the end of a network stream:

1. Have the sender send the length (an int or long) as the first 4 (or 8) bytes of the stream. The receiver reads this length and then continues to read the stream until it's read that many bytes.
2. Agree on an "end of stream" marker. This can take many forms. For simple streams that contain only ASCII strings, for example, you could agree that a byte value of 255 means end of string. Or you could use the ASCII EOT character. For record-oriented strings, the first byte of the record could be the record type, and a record type of 0xFF could mean "End of records."

In other words, a network stream can't know when it's at the end. Not like a file stream can. You have to encode the stream length or end of stream marker in your data.

### Update

Documentation for [System.Drawing.Image.FromStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/93z9ee4x.aspx) says:

> The stream is reset to zero if this method is called successively with the same stream.

So you can't use that method to read multiple images from the same stream.

I suspect what you'll need to do is change your data so that it is structured like this:

```
length | data for image 1 | length | data for image 2 | 0
```

Then you'll read the length, read that many bytes into a byte array, and create the image from that byte array (perhaps by wrapping a memory stream around it), then read the next length, the next block of bytes, etc., until you read a length of 0, which signifies the end of the stream.

Comment: Okay, but in the first example. How can i implement it in the Stream? i currently have such method with BinaryWriter, but i would prefer not to use a wrapper and just use the stream (as low level as possible).